# How to get values in an array of objects using another array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that interacts with 2 arrays, 1st array is an array of objects that contain my dropdown options, second array is an array of values. I'm trying to filter the 1st array to return what has matched the values in my 2nd array. How do I achieve this?

1st Array:

```
const books = [
    {
        label: "To Kill a Mockingbird",
        value: 1
    },
    {
        label: "1984",
        value: 2
    },
    {
        label: "The Lord of the Rings",
        value: 3
    },
    {
        label: "The Great Gatsby",
        value: 4
    }
]
```

Code Snippet below:

```
const idString = "1,2,3";

function getSelectedOption(idString, books) {
        const ids = idString.split(",");
        const selectedOptions = [];

        ids.map(e => {
            const selected = books.map(options => {
                if (options.value === e){
                    return {
                        label: options.label,
                        value: options.value
                    }
                }
            })
            selectedOptions.push(selected)
        })

        return selectedOptions
    }
```

Result:

```
[
    [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
    [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
    [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    {
        label: "To Kill a Mockingbird",
        value: 1
    },
    {
        label: "1984",
        value: 2
    },
    {
        label: "The Lord of the Rings",
        value: 3
    }
]
```

Comment: Please have a look at what [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) actually does and why it is not the right tool in this case. If you're not interested in its return value you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Have a look at what [`===` (_strict_ equal)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) does. `e` is a string, `options.value` a number

Comment: How do you call the `getSelectedOption` function? You want to filter objects, so why not use `.filter()` method? `.map()` always returns a value. If you don't return any value, returned array will have `undefined` value at the index for which you didn't return any value.

Comment: `books.filter(book => /* do something with book.value and ids that will return true/false */)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that value is unique,  you can update your code as following to get them in order.

```
const idString = "1,2,3";

function getSelectedOption(idString, books) {
  const ids = idString.split(",");
  return ids.map(id => books.find(book => book.value == id)).filter(Boolean)
}
```

You can also filter the books array if you don't care about the order or in case that the `value` is not unique.

```
const idString = "1,2,3";

function getSelectedOption(idString, books) {
  const ids = idString.split(",");
  return books.filter(book => ids.includes(book.value.toString()))
}
```

Please note that these are O(n*m) algorithms and it should not be used with large sets of data, however if one of the arrays is relatively small you can use it.

Comment: Two problems in your code. 1. array returned by `ids.map(...)` will have undefined value if `idString` contains any any id that isn't in `books` array. You might want to use `.filter()` instead of `.map()`. 2. `book.value` is a number whereas `id` is a string, so `book.value === id` will always be false.

Comment: First option looks like it can work for me, just needed to change ```===``` to ```==```

Comment: @GJosh `.map()` is not the right method to use in your case. use `.filter()`.

Comment: @Yousaf can you please clarify why is the `.map()` method not the right method ?

Comment: `.map()` method is meant to construct a new array that contains the transformed values of the array on which `.map()` method was called. It is not meant to _filter_ array elements. As i mentioned in my first comment, array returned by `ids.map(...)` will have `undefined` value if `idString` contains any id that isn't in books array. In first code example in your answer, if `idString` is `'1,2,3,5'`, last element of the returned array will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Yousaf that can be  fixed by passing a `.filter(Boolean)` to the result.
Both methods are valid, if you care about the order of the elements and use the second one + use a sorting algorithm it would be very slow.

Comment: `.filter()` preserves order.

Comment: @Yousaf it preserves the order of the array not the same order as the requested sequence in ids array.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getSelectedOption(idString, books) {
    const idArray = convertStringToArray(idString)
    return books.filter(item => idString.includes(item.value))
}

function convertStringToArray(string) {
    return string.split(",")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an array `filter`:

```js
function getSelectedOption(idString, books) {
  const ids = idString.split(",");
  return books.filter((item) => ids.includes(item.value.toString()));
}

const books = [{
    label: "To Kill a Mockingbird",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "1984",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "The Great Gatsby",
    value: 4
  }
]

const idString = "1,2,3";

getSelectedOption(idString, books);

console.log(getSelectedOption(idString, books));
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes to your solution

- After split `idString`, it would result in array of string value, so you have to cast it to number
- Instead of use `map` to get selected, you should use `find`

```js
const books = [
  {
    label: 'To Kill a Mockingbird',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: '1984',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: 'The Lord of the Rings',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: 'The Great Gatsby',
    value: 4
  }
]

const idString = '1,2,3'

function getSelectedOption(idString, books) {
  const ids = idString.split(',').map(Number)
  const selectedOptions = []

  ids.forEach(e => {
    const selected = books
      .map(options => {
        if (options.value === e) {
          return {
            label: options.label,
            value: options.value
          }
        }
      })
      .filter(options => options !== undefined)
    selectedOptions.push(selected[0])
  })

  return selectedOptions
}

console.log(getSelectedOption(idString, books))
```